# Asp:Gridview Estilo de botón dinámico según dato

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Como puedo cambiar el estilo de un ButtonField según el dato que cargue dentro de él, en un asp:Gridview.

Tengo una tabla Equipos:

> idEquipo NroInterno Marca Modelo Estado_Final

Estado final puede ser OP o FS (Operativo, Fuera de Servicio)

Entonces al Bindear los datos en un Gridview quiero poner el botón en rojo cuando sea FS o verde si es OP

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEquipos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="IdEquipo" ReadOnly="true" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nro Interno" DataField="NroInterno" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Marca" DataField="Marca" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Modelo" DataField="Modelo" />
      <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Estado Final" ButtonType="Link" DataTextField="Estado_Final" ControlStyle-CssClass=/*ESTO QUIERO QUE SE CAMBIE SEGUN EL DATO*/">
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Utiliza el evento RowDatabound
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No encuentro la lógica para hacerlo.

Comment: En que IDE estas desarrollando? yo lo hado en Visual Studio:

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, como puedo acceder al contenido del ButtonField dentro del evento RowDataBound ?

Comment: Te puse un ejemplo, el RowDatabound es del Grid.. ojo